# Focus Event on LinkLabel- C#

Tags: c#

I'm new in c#. Is there a code. When I point the mouse pointer on a specific 'linklabel'. It will do some function. For example. When I point the mouse pointer on a specific linklabel. Its forecolor will change. But when I leave the mouse pointer it will back to normal. Can you give me a simple code for that? Thank You!

Comment: You should add a tag for the technology you are using: winforms, wpf, asp, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Windows forms controls (including the [`LinkLabel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel(v=vs.110).aspx) control) has a [`MouseHover`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover(v=vs.110).aspx) event and a [`MouseLeave`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

These can be used to perform actions when the mouse hovers over a LinkLabel.

#### Example

```
//Name of the LinkLabel is linkLabel1

private void linkLabel1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    linkLabel1.LinkColor = Color.Red;
}

private void linkLabel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    linkLabel1.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
}
```